# Сравнить 2 объекта и вернуть объект с одинаковыми ключами

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как сделать:

```
const obj1 = {
firstName: "Иванов",
lastName: "Иван",
middleName: "Иванович"  
}

const obj2 = {
firstName: "Сидоров",
lastName: "Олег",
}
```

Нужно сравнить obj1 и obj2 и вернуть obj1 только с теми ключами(не значениями) которые есть в obj2.

Comment: Пробовали в цикле перебирать свойства?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я правильно понял, что значения сравнивать не нужно - только проверять наличие свойств одного объекта в другом?

```
const func = (obj1, obj2) => {
    let result = {};
    for (let prop in obj1) {
        if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) result[prop] = obj1[prop];
    };
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ну ещё и вернуть значения obj1

Comment: Окей, теперь понял, поправил ответ

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(obj1, function(key, value){
  if(!(key in obj2)){
    delete obj1[key]
  }
})
```

На выходе получим obj1 только с нужными ключами